# Xamarin forms read file on start app and save on close

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to save config file. My save and load function works correctly when I call it from the button. But I want to improve it and save my file and load when app is closing /opening. These methods are on MainPage.xaml.cs.

```
 protected override void OnStart()
    {
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        mainPage.Load_File();

    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        mainPage.Save_File();
    }
```

When I created it like this save and load not working.

Comment: why would you create a new instance of `MainPage` in `OnSleep`?  Is there a reason that your `Save_File()` can't live in your `App` class?  Or just save the config file every time its modified?

Comment: They can't becouse my whole code is in MainPage class. I need to execute method Save_FIle / Load_File which are part of MainPage class.

Comment: then there is no need to create a new instance of `MainPage` in `OnSleep`, just use the reference you already have

Comment: Can you explain me how can I do it?  MainPage.Save_File(); When I am trying to make it like this its not working. I will be very thankfull.

Comment: @JohnyPuszka If the answer solves your problem, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:)?

Comment: Yes, I did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create your `MainPage`, save a reference to it so you can reuse it later

```
MainPage main;

public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    MainPage = main = new MainPage();
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    main.Load_File();
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    main.Save_File();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I stucked on this. I can keep moving forward :)